# Sort Postgresql table using previously calculated data

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I have an operation which gives me a list of IDs and some score related to these IDs.
Then I need query the database and sort rows using the data above.

I tried something like (I'm using PostgreSQL):

```
SELECT * FROM sometable
LEFT OUTER JOIN (VALUES (629, 3), (624, 1))  /* Here is my data */
AS x(id, ordering)
USING (id)
WHERE some_column_id=1
ORDER BY x.ordering;
```

But for ~10000 rows it runs about 15sec on my machine.
Is there a better way to sort my table using a previously calculated data?

Comment: A case expression in the ORDER BY?

Comment: @jarlh will it be OK for say ~1000 clauses in the CASE expression?

Comment: If that many, consider a help table!

Comment: Write the ids and ordering into a temporary table (if they are not *already* in a table).  Add an index on `id` and run the query.

Answer (score 1):

What is the performance of this version?

```
SELECT st.*
FROM sometable st
WHERE st.some_column_id = 1
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN st.id = 629 then 3 WHEN st.id = 624 THEN 1 END);
```

An index on `sometable(some_column_id)` might also speed the query.

However, I don't understand why your version on a table with 10,000 rows would take 15 seconds.

Comment: Well, I tried my and your solution on another database with even more rows, and this works pretty fast, seems like an issue with my local database... (There already is an index on `some_column_id`).

Comment: Will it be executing slow if there will be about ~1000 cases?

Comment: @coldmind . . . That would probably slow it down considerably.  You should probably use a (temp) table with an index.